# How to Execute Command in Trigger?

Tags: wpf

```
<Combobox.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Combobox}">
  <Style.Triggers>

    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
 //////    I want to execute command here/////
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is it possible to execute command here if there are another way then please tell me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, this is a real pain in WPF and you'll need to fall back to an external framework as it's not supported in the standard libraries. This sort of thing highlights how WPF and MVVM are hacked together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by modifying your item template of combo box.. Use Button as Combo box item in the combo box. You can do a command binding to that button and change the Click mode to Hover.

Answer (score 0):

Several frameworks offer ways to execute commands using events, for example the CINCH framework which you will find on www.codeproject.com . Instead of using a Trigger, thus you could use the MouseOver event to execute your command.